# WPF Best way store if the user has completed something

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating an application that uses some sensors that are connected through a serial connection. Prior to recording actual sensor data I need the user to capture 60 seconds of calibration data where the sensors are not doing anything. This captured data is then used as a starting point for later data processing.

The application is to prompt the user to calibrate the sensors when the application is opened or before they start recording (if calibration hasn't been completed when the application started, or if the application has been left open overnight and it is a new calendar day since the last calibration).

What is the best way to manage this? Should I have a variable somewhere that stores the status if calibration has been completed or not? Or would it be best to store the date and time with the calibration data and run a check on this data to see when the last calibration was completed?

I am new to WPF programming and want to know the best way to manage this kind of thing. I'm guessing it is better if possible to run a check than have a variable store the status? If I had to store the status somewhere what would be the best way to do this? The use of global variables is obviously frowned upon.

Comment: It depends. It depends on what you want the application to do and what is best for the application and your logic. Obviously to store data "permanently" so you can come back to it would be either a SQL DB or perhaps in your settings file (again, depends on your situation). But if it is a one time thing then the use of global variables is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use application settings to store last validationtime.
It is an easy way to store data, in a strongly type way without having to use a database.
Go to properties/Settings.settings.
Add a LastCalibration property of type System.DateTime
Compile
In your Settings.settings.cs code, you now have :

```
internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase {

    private static Settings defaultInstance = ((Settings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Settings())));

    // ...

    [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    public global::System.DateTime LastCalibrationTime {
        get {
            return ((global::System.DateTime)(this["LastCalibration"]));
        }
        set {
            this["LastCalibration"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can :

```
// read
DateTime lastCalibration = Settings.Default.LastCalibration;

// save
Settings.Default.LastCalibration = DateTime.Now;
Settings.Default.Save();
```

Regards